# GIT: Merge one folder from repository A to a different folder in repo B

Tags: git, merge

I have two git repositories with different structures. Lets call them private and opensource.

The private repo has this(ish) structure:

```
root
-nextRevision
--Firmware
-otherFolders
```

The opensource repo has this(ish) structure:

```
root
-Firmware
-otherFolders
```

I need to merge the Firmware folder from the opensource (which is directly in the root folder) into the private repo (where it's in the nextRevision folder).

I tried all my git-fu, which is not a lot. I tried different merge strategies but I always end up with the problem of different structures of the repositories.

Comment: is one of them a fork of the other? rather, do they share history together?

Comment: "I need to merge" define _merge_ please? Do you mean report the state of one into another or do you need the full history with?

Comment: The private repo diverged from the opensource one years ago. Now, there was some development in the opensource one and I need to merge that code into the private repo. The only codebase they share is in the Firmware folder. Keeping the history would be nice but not necessary.

Comment: So to answer the question "is one of them a fork of the other? rather, do they share history together?" - yes, but only when it comes to the Firmware folder (and few others but those are irrelevant to me)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the same thing:

1. Clone both repos
2. Change the folder structure of the one you want to merge (only the folders you need) using `git mv` (so it's the same as the destination repo) and commit your changes
3. Add the **local** version of the repo you need to merge as a remote into the main repo
4. `git merge --no-commit --no-ff repo-to-merge/master`
5. Delete all the files you don't need using `git reset -- filename`
6. Resolve merge conflicts
7. Commit the changes